# routes singular controller name

Tags: cakephp, routes, url-routing

I think `Routes` class is really powerful.. And we create many URLs structures with it. (but I don't know how :( )

I'm a beginner.. How can I change plural controller names in URLs? for example change:

```
http://example.com/fruits/lemon
```

to

```
http://example.com/fruit/lemon
```

(for all controllers)
Is it possible at all? or because controllers are defined with plural names (`FruitsController`) it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
Router::connect(
    '/fruit/:action/*', array('controller' => 'fruits')
);
```

This way, any action called at `/fruit/whatever`(url bar) will now connect to `/fruits/whatever`(internally) !

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

Comment: I'll test some stuff to see if this is possible, I'll be back

Comment: As right now, I haven't found anything. It's probably possible by overloading the lib that does the rooting but...!

Comment: Name your controller FruitController. That should work. If it does, rename your controllers to singular.